# Delphi Math: Why is 0.7<0.70?

Tags: delphi, math, comparison, floating-point, types

If I have variables a, b, an c of type double, let c:=a/b, and give a and b values of 7 and 10, then c's value of 0.7 registers as being LESS THAN 0.70.

On the other hand, if the variables are all type extended, then c's value of 0.7 does not register as being less than 0.70.

This seems strange. What information am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/java-floating-point-arithmetic

Comment: This is one of the most common (the most common?) questions on SO, and has nothing in particular to do with Delphi, but with the way comptuers store floating-point numbers.

Comment: Not that that stops it from getting upvoted :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193554/trouble-with-float-in-objective-c-solved

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Lars -- I accepted a response, although they all worked pretty well from my perspective (...as did responses to the similar questions ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no representation for the mathematical number `0.7` in binary floating-point. Your statement computes in `c` the closest `double`, which (according to what you say, I didn't check) is a little below 0.7.

Apparently in extended precision the closest floating-point number to 0.7 is a little above it. But there still is no exact representation for 0.7. There isn't any at any precision in binary floating-point.

As a rule of thumb, any non-integer number whose last non-zero decimal is not 5 cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating-point number (the converse is not true: 0.05 cannot be represented exactly either).

Answer (score 18):

First, it needs to be noted that float literals in Delphi are of the Extended type. So when you compare a double to a literal, the double is probably first "expanded" to Extended, and then compared. (Edit : This is true only in 32 bits application. In 64 bits application, `Extended` is an alias of `Double`)

Here, all ShowMessage will be displayed.

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  A, B : Double;
begin
  A := 7/10;
  B := 0.7; //Here, we lower the precision of "0.7" to double

  //Here, A is expanded to Extended...  But it has already lost precision. This is (kind of) similar to doing Round(0.7) <> 0.7
  if A <> 0.7 then 
    ShowMessage('Weird');

  if A = B then //Here it would work correctly.
    ShowMessage('Ok...');

  //Still... the best way to go...
  if SameValue(A, 0.7, 0.0001) then
    ShowMessage('That will never fails you');
end;
```

Here some literature for you

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: +1 for _the_ canonical link regarding floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 8):

It has to do with the number of digits of precision in the two different floating point types you're using, and the fact that a lot of numbers cannot be represented exactly, regardless of precision. (From the pure math side: irrational numbers outnumber rationals)

Take 2/3, for example.  It' can't be represented exactly in decimal.  With 4 significant digits, it would be represented as 0.6667.  With 8 significant digits, it would be 0.66666667.
The trailing 7 is roundup reflecting that the next digit would be > 5 if there was room to keep it.

0.6667 is greater than 0.66666667, so the computer will evaluate 2/3 (4 digits) > 2/3 (8 digits).

The same is true with your .7 vs .70 in double and extended vars.

To avoid this specific issue, try to use the same numeric type throughout your code.  When working with floating point numbers in general, there are a lot of little things you have to watch out for.  The biggest is to not write your code to compare two floats for equality - even if they should be the same value, there are many factors in calculations that can make them end up a very tiny bit different.  Instead of comparing for equality, you need to test that the difference between the two numbers is very small.  How small the difference has to be is up to you and to the nature of your calculations, and it usually referred to as epsilon, taken from calculus theorem and proof.

Comment: Actually, all the computable numbers can be represented exactly :)

Comment: I think this is a reasonable explanation, but I would add that "many numbers that have a rational terminating decimal representation do not have a precise terminating (rational) binary floating point representation". That fact seems to escape a lot of developer's notice.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing [This Thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

See especially the '**Accuracy problems**' chapter. See also the Pascal's answer.
In order to fix your code without using the `Extended` type, you must add the `Math` unit and use the [`SameValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Math.SameValue) function from there which is especially built for this purpose.

Be sure to use an `Epsilon` value different than 0 when you use the SameValue in your case.

For example:

```
var
  a, b, c: double;


begin
  a:=7; b:=10;
  c:=a/b;

  if SameValue(c, 0.70, 0.001) then
    ShowMessage('Ok')
  else
    ShowMessage('Wrong!');
end;
```

HTH