# float result is inaccurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with floats in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193554/trouble-with-floats-in-objective-c)

It might sound to you like a basic issue, but I'm trying for 2 days to figure it out.
I searched for a solution and the only explanation I found is that float uses only 4-bytes of memory. (that's helpful...)
I have the following loop:

```
double x = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
        {
            x = x + 0.01;
            NSLog(@"%f",x);
        }
```

and it prints:

```
0.010000
0.020000
0.030000
.
.
1.000000
```

but when I change the double to float:

```
0.010000
0.020000
0.030000
.
.
0.820000
0.830000
0.839999
0.849999
.
.
0.999999
```

As you can see, the computer can't calculate 0.840000 as float -_-
The problem is that I have to use float because I'm using the UIProgressView that can take a float number between 0.0 to 1.0.

If I can't use double, what can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you wrote the following code:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
{
    x = x + 3.5;
    NSLog(@"%d",x);
}
```

you wouldn't be surprised that it doesn't print out `3.5`, `7.0`, `10.5`, right?  Would you say that "int is inaccurate"?  Of course not.

Exactly the same thing is happening in your example.  Just like `3.5` isn't representable as an integer, `0.01` isn't representable as a double.  The actual value you get is:

```
0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375
```

Now, you accumulate not only the initial *representation* error from rounding `0.1` to double, but you also get *rounding* errors because not all of the intermediate sums are representable.  This second source of error does not occur in the `int` example.  The actual intermediate sums that are computed are:

```
0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375
0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875
0.0299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
0.040000000000000000832667268468867405317723751068115234375
0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125
0.060000000000000004718447854656915296800434589385986328125
...
0.990000000000000657252030578092671930789947509765625
1.0000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875
```

when you round these to six decimal places via the `%f` format specifier, you get yet a third source of rounding, but the errors are all small enough that the results you "expect" are printed out.

Now let's look at what happens when you use `float` instead of `double`; because of the C arithmetic operand promotion rules, the additions are all carried out in `double`, but the result is rounded back to `float` after each addition -- yet another rounding.  The sequence of intermediate values is as follows:

```
0.00999999977648258209228515625
0.0199999995529651641845703125
0.02999999932944774627685546875
0.039999999105930328369140625
0.0500000007450580596923828125
0.060000002384185791015625
...
0.809999525547027587890625
0.819999516010284423828125
0.829999506473541259765625
```

Up to this point, the errors are small enough that they all still produce the "expected" value when rounded to six decimal digits.  However, the next value computed is

```
0.839999496936798095703125
```

Because this is just *smaller* than the exact halfway case for rounding to six decimal digits:

```
0.8399995
```

it rounds down, and the number that is printed is:

```
0.8399999
```

---

Now, what can you do about it? The reason that the errors eventually become large enough to appear when printed with six decimal digits is that you are *accumulating* error with each sequential addition.  If you can avoid this accumulation, the error will remain small enough to not cause this trouble.  There are a several easy ways to avoid this cumulative error; perhaps the easiest is:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    float x = (i+1)/100.f;
    NSLog(@"%d",x);
}
```

This works because both `i + 1` and `100.f` are exactly represented in `float`.  There is thus only a single rounding, which occurs in the division, so the `float` result is as close to your desired number as possible; there is no way you can come any closer.

Comment: Thank you, now it's much clearer than before!

Answer (score 3):

Use `x = (i + 1) * 0.01;` instead of `x = x + 0.01;`. It's still inaccurate as `float` simply cannot exactly represent `0.84`, but at least the errors don't accumulate.