# Problem in double.Parse in Managed C++

Tags: .net, double, precision, managed-c++

I am getting a weird problem while parsing a double value in managed C++.  It may be that I am doing something wrong.  When I do:

```
double value = 0.006;
result = Math::Parse( value)
```

The output of result is `0.006000000000001`.  Why it is appending a 1?

Also when I go an round the value to 5 decimal places, it fails.  I am doing:

```
result2 = Math::Round(result, 5)
```

But `result2` is always `0.006000000000001`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal. This problem caused by IEEE format of double - in real 0.006 is represented as approximation of infinite binary fraction.
So you have 3 ways -

- use corresponding string formating to output
- use Decimal type
- don't use == to compare numbers, instead use < or > with constant error,e.g: (X -0.06) < Error

Answer (score 3):

This is due to precision. I gave this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193554/trouble-with-float-in-objective-c-solved/1193607#1193607):

> Floats and doubles are number
>   representations with a certain
>   precision. Not every value can be
>   represented in this format. See
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960072/rounding-errors) as well.
>
> You can easily think of why this would
>   be the case: there is an unlimited
>   number of number just in the intervall
>   (1..1), but a float only has a limited
>   number of bits to represent all
>   numbers in (-MAXFLOAT..MAXFLOAT).
>
> More aptly put: in a 32bit integer
>   representation there is a countable
>   number of integers to be represented,
>   But there is an infinite innumerable
>   number of real values that cannot be
>   fully represented in a limited
>   representation of 32 or 64bit.
>   Therefore there not only is a limit to
>   the highest and lowest representable
>   real value, but also to the accuracy.
>
> So why is a number that has little
>   digits after the floating point
>   affected? Because the representation
>   is based on a binary system instead of
>   a decimal, making other numbers easily
>   represented then the decimal ones.

Answer (score 0):

double precision numbers are essentially approximations, and frequently have tails that you **cannot get rid of** - i.e. there is no way of expressing the number more accurately.

You might get results more like you expect if you use `decimal` - which is still an approximation, but it uses base-10, so tends to behave more like people expect. But because it doesn't map to a CPU type, it is slower.