# Javascript - slight division error

Tags: javascript, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Math Error: Inexact Floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556789/javascript-math-error-inexact-floats)

I did this

```
this.cues = []
for(var i, i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
    cue = this.length * (i/8.0)
   this.cues.push(cue)
```

where this.length is a double. I checked the division and found that I was off by .000002 up to about the fourth array cell.

1. Is there any javascript-specific cause for this anybody can think of? It may just be the environment, so if not no big deal
2. If so, can I fix it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Another double - which I get, it's just off by .000002

Comment: There should be no reason for this to be off, since 8.0 is perfectly representable in IEEE-754, as should your reasonably-sized integers divided by it.

Comment: What is the value of `this.length` anyways?

Comment: 375.386658 - interesting, a single voice of dissent but an extremely high-rep one :)

Comment: *That* would be why then; your original number *isn't* exactly precise. `>>> (375.386658).hex()`
`'0x1.7762fc04c8bcap+8'`
`>>> '%.25f' % 375.386658`
`'375.3866580000000112704583444'`

Comment: OK - will study referenced documentation, ty

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) operations on computers have [small accuracy errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) like this because of the way they are stored internally in a computer. For more information, I recommend you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Answer (score 0):

You should read: *"[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)"*. This is simply how floating point numbers are represented on a computer.