# Javascript adding 0.1 to 0.2 causes 0.30000000000000004

Tags: javascript, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Math Error: Inexact Floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556789/javascript-math-error-inexact-floats)

I have the following code to make an animation (doIt does the animation but not related).

```
function recur(max, i){
    console.log("i: " + i);
    if ( i <= 1){
        setTimeout(function(){
            // doIt(max,i);
            recur(max, i + 0.1);                
        },100);
    } else {
        // OK
    }
}
recur(16,0);
```

However, the i values are not consistent. For the following code the output is (Google Chrome 20):

```
i: 0 
i: 0.1 
i: 0.2 
i: 0.30000000000000004
i: 0.4 
i: 0.5 
i: 0.6 
i: 0.7 
i: 0.7999999999999999 
i: 0.8999999999999999 
i: 0.9999999999999999 
i: 1.0999999999999999
```

Why is this happening? I want 0.3 not a so close number. Unfortunately this happens in every iteration.

Comment: The question appeared a few minutes ago too (the answers are identical, copy-paste): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284981/javascript-slight-division-error

Comment: Downvoting does not help, it did not appear in the similar questions part.. ANd there is much examples in every language, but each one of is downvoted.. Why?

Comment: Not my downvote. Upon hover over the downvote icon, you see "This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)". This question has been asked several times, and was easily found by entering the keywords in the search engine/Google. [Copy-paste your title in Stack Overflow's search engine](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=javascript%20adding%200.1%20to%200.2%20causes%200.30000000000000004), and several duplicates appear. [Same for Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Javascript+adding+0.1+to+0.2+causes+0.30000000000000004)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To output `0.3`, you can use `toFixed` and floating point numbers have slight mis-calculations as @Oleksi pointed out.

```
console.log((0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(1)); // 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) operations on computers have [small accuracy errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) like this because of the way they are stored internally in a computer. For more information, I recommend you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Questions similar to this get asked quite a lot. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556789/javascript-math-error-inexact-floats).

Comment: If you're aware that this is essentially a duplicate, you should just vote-to-close as a duplicate, rather than posting an answer...