# Why doesn't this NSPredicate work?

Tags: cocoa, performance, comparison, predicate, nspredicate

I have an Array of `MKAnnotation` objects called `arrAnnotations`. I want to pick out one of the annotations with the same coordinate as the one stored in a `CLLocation` object called "newLocation".

I'm trying to use a `NSPredicate`, but it doesn't work.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.coordinate == %f)", newLocation.coordinate];
NSArray* filteredArray = [arrAnnotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

The filteredArray always contains zero objects.

I have also tried the following, which do not work either

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"(coordinate == %f)", newLocation.coordinate];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"(coordinate > 0)"];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"(coordinate.latitude == %f)", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

The last two crash the app, the third one with an `NSInvalidArgumentException` for `[NSConcreteValue compare:]` and the fourth, because `latitude` is not key-value-coding-compliant (I assume this is because coordinate is just a `c-struct` and not an `NSObject`?).

How can I make this work with `NSPredicate`? 
Can anyone give me a link to a document that shows how Predicates work under the hood? 
I don't understand what they actually do, even though I have read and understood most of Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001792-DontLinkElementID_2).
Is searching a huge array with predicates more efficient than just looping through it with a for...in construct? If yes/no, why?

Comment: You can't just interpret a struct as a `double`. You might get something out with `NSLog(@"%f", aCoordinate)` but that is undefined behaviour and can lead to crashes etc. As `NSPredicate` doesn't work with C-structs you could use explicit tests for the moment unless someone with experience in CoreLocation knows of a better alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MKAnnotation protocol's coordinate property is a [CLLocationCoordinate2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238-CH2-SW15) `struct`, thus it is not allowed in `NSPredicate` format syntax according to the [Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795)

You could use `NSPredicate` `predicateWithBlock:` instead to accomplish what you are trying to do, but you have be careful with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and how to compare it for equality.

`CLLocationCoordinate2D`'s `latitude` and `longitude` property are [CLLocationDegrees](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238-CH2-SW19) data type, which is a `double` by definition.

With a quick search you can find several examples of problems you would face when comparing floating point values for equality. Some good examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732645/iphone-objective-c-comparing-doubles-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193554/trouble-with-floats-in-objective-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960072/rounding-errors).

Given all that, I believe that using code bellow for your predicate might solve your problem.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = evaluatedObject;

    if (fabsf([annotation coordinate].latitude - [newLocation coordinate].latitude) < 0.000001 
            && fabsf([annotation coordinate].longitude - [newLocation coordinate].longitude) < 0.000001) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

}];
```