# Getting strange result in Double value comparision iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, double

i am doing very basic calculations and getting the weird result when i am comparing double values in `if.. statement`. See the screenshot attached.
[image]

I marked the variable value with Red markers. You can see the value of variable `totalSliceValue` is 100 and when i compared the value with `100.0` it return `TRUE`, but **100 is not greater than 100**.

Can anybody explain this why i am getting this. Is there any bug in my code or it is an issue with the compiler.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the value isn't really something like `100.0000001`? Try this: `NSLog(@"totalSliceValue = %.8f", totalSliceValue);

Comment: @rmaddy : I tried with .8f and getting '100.00000000'.

Comment: Correct, when i tried with .16f and printed the value, it comes out to be 100.0000000000000142.

Answer (score 1):

When it's a double, 100 is often greater than 100. Or less. It is actually 100.000000000127832645 or something like that.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[Another of many articles on the problem developers face when working with floats and doubles.](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)

Solution: subtract one double for another and check that the result is so small that you can treat them as equal, not that they are equal.

[One duplicate StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4732645/189804)

[Another duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193554/trouble-with-floats-in-objective-c)

The problem isn't really with the compiler but the way you are instructing it - it's working according to the rules for IEEE floating point.

Comment: Correct, when i tried with .16f and printed the value, it comes out to be 100.0000000000000142.