# How to remove the line under the UISearchController on iOS 11?

Tags: swift, ios11, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

How can I remove the line under the `UISearchController` on iOS 11?

I've added the `UISearchController` using this code:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

but after doing that there is a weird line under it:

[image]

Any advice on how to remove the line or at least choose its color would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that is what is called a `hairline`. Search for that term and you'll find a variety of solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another solution, a weak one but it could be useful in specific use-case.

```swift
extension UISearchController {

    var hairlineView: UIView? {
        guard let barBackgroundView = self.searchBar.superview?.subviews.filter({ String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UIBarBackground" }).first
        else { return nil }

        return barBackgroundView.subviews.filter({ $0.bounds.height == 1 / self.traitCollection.displayScale }).first
    }
}
```

With that extension, you only have to write the following code in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller:

```swift
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    // Remove hairline from the searchBar.
    self.navigationItem.searchController?.hairlineView?.isHidden = true
}
```

---

## Important:

Please note that this solution is really weak and can break with future iOS updates. 
Furthermore, `$0.bounds.height == 1 / self.traitCollection.displayScale` is unsafe and I advise you to use [a proper float comparison method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732704/2370723).

Comment: thank you Vin for contributing. I will mark it as correct since it's the best that we currently have :)

Answer (score 2):

A hacky solution, but the best I have for now, is adding a white line view overlapping the dark line:

```
let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height-4, width: view.bounds.width, height: 1))
lineView.backgroundColor = .white
searchController.searchBar.addSubview(lineView)
```

Comment: Did you find a cleaner solution?

Comment: @VinGazoil Sadly no. Ended up adding a search icon in the upper right corner that opens a new screen with search functionality. Please come back and post your answer if you end up solving this weird issue. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you added it as a subview, you will found a glitch when press back or go forward to another page. This could improve your solution @budidino

```
let lineView = UIView(frame: .zero)
lineView.backgroundColor = .white
searchController.searchBar.addSubview(lineView)

lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
lineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.searchBar.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
lineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.searchBar.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
lineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
lineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

in iOS11

```
@interface UISearchController (Additions)
- (void)hideHairLineView;
@end
```

```
@implementation UISearchController (Additions)
- (void)hideHairLineView{
    UIView *barBackgroundView = self.searchBar.superview.subviews.firstObject;
    for(UIView *v in barBackgroundView.subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            UIImageView *imgView= (UIImageView *)v;
            if (imgView.frame.size.height <= 1.0) {
                [imgView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self.navigationItem.searchController hideHairLineView];
}
```

in iOS13

from `viewDidLoad` add
`[self.navigationController setDelegate:self];`

```
#pragma mark - UINavigationControllerDelegate

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.viewForLastBaselineLayout setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```