# Double multiplied by 100 and then cast to long is giving wrong value

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers

I have the following code:

```
Double i=17.31;
long j=(long) (i*100);
System.out.println(j);
```

O/P : `1730   //Expected:1731`

```
Double i=17.33;
long j=(long) (i*100);
System.out.println(j);
```

O/P : `1732    //Expected:1733`

```
Double i=17.32;
long j=(long) (i*100);
System.out.println(j);
```

O/P : `1732    //Expected:1732{As expected}`

```
Double i=15.33;
long j=(long) (i*100);
System.out.println(j);
```

O/P : `1533    //Expected:1533{as Expected}`

I have tried to Google but unable to find reason.I am sorry if the question is trivial.

Comment: Not sure, hence the comment but this could be due to rounding issues. If that is the case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960072/rounding-errors) previous SO thread should be of help. The [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class should help reduce these errors.

Comment: Why do people keep massively updated each iteration of  "Q: 'Floating point weirdness'  A: 'IEEE-754'" instead of flagging/voting to close as exact duplicate?

Comment: As a matter of habit, if you want to convert a decimal number to an int and the function you want to use truncates, add .5 before truncating.  It will give you a better rounding (1.75 will round to 2 instead of 1) but most importantly will avoid this problem.

Comment: @DanNeely I looked for a duplicate, but couldn't find one addressing the rounding issue exactly. Everyone links to [**this damn doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) which is long enought to be book in itself. :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

None of the answers seem to deal with **why** `17.32` acted different.

#### 1. Why it occurred

The difference in behaviour you see between `17.32` and `17.33 & 17.31` is due to IEEE-754 **Rounding** rules.

Rounding rule applied: from, [The Java™ Virtual
Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/jvms7.pdf) *§2.8.1*

> The rounding operations of the Java virtual machine always use IEEE
>   754 round to nearest mode. Inexact results are rounded to the nearest
>   representable value, with ties going to the value with a zero
>   least-significant bit. This is the IEEE 754 default mode. The Java virtual
>   machine does not give any means to change the floating-point rounding
>   mode

---

#### 2. Your case:

*Double is*: (1 sign-bit + 11 exponent-bits + 52 fraction-bits = 64bits). *Internal representation after rounding* below:

```
             1 [63]      11 [62-52]           52 [51-00]
              Sign        Exponent             Fraction

17.31 -->    0 (+)       10000000011 (+4)     1.0001010011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111
17.32 -->    0 (+)       10000000011 (+4)     1.0001010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010010 //rounded up
17.33 -->    0 (+)       10000000011 (+4)     1.0001010101000111101011100001010001111010111000010100
```

---

#### 3. Internal representation (Proof):

17.31: (Mantissa comparison)

```
Actual:   1.00010100111101011100001010001111010111000010100011110...
Internal: 1.0001010011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111
```

17.32: (Mantissa comparison)

```
Actual:   1.00010101000111101011100001010001111010111000010100011... 
Internal: 1.0001010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010010    //round-up!
```

17.33: (Mantissa comparison)

```
Actual:   1.00010101010001111010111000010100011110101110000101000...
Internal: 1.0001010101000111101011100001010001111010111000010100
```

---

#### 4. Conversion back-to-decimal:

```
17.31 ->  17.309999999999998721023075631819665431976318359375...
17.32 ->  17.32000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125... //(was rounded up)
17.33 ->  17.3299999999999982946974341757595539093017578125...
```

(**[IEEE-754 Analysis Tool](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)**)

#### 5. Cast to long

**EDIT:** There is a factor more at play at your multiplication step as @Jeppe Stig Nielsen said. The result of the **FP** multiplication (**[Reference](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF)**) step does its own rounding-towards-nearest.
This changes which results are as expected and which aren't, but the reason is still exactly the same as stated above.

Finally, due to the cast `(long)`, truncation occurs, and leaves you with the results you see. `(1730, 1732, 1732)`

Narrowing Primitive Conversion : [The Java™ Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) *§5.1.3*

> If the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point
>   value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using
>   IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode

Comment: Upvoted this answer also because of the link to the nice tool. But: Remember that the multiplication by `100.0` leads to further rounding. Consider the case **`17.34`**. The representation of this number as a `Double` _also_ has to be rounded _down_. But it still gives the expected output after multiplying by `100.0`! The reason is that part of the multiplication algorithm is to round to get rid of digits that can't fit into the result `Double`. In the case of `17.34 * 100.0` the rounding _after_ multiplying is a round-_up_, and therefore we're lucky to get the "expected" result.

Answer (score 22):

The `double` value is represented not as 17.31, but as 17.309999999999999. That's why when you multiply it by 100 you get 1730.99999999999999999. After conversion to `Long` your `double` value is truncated towards zero. So you get 1730.

Comment: 17.32 isn't stored as 17.319999999999999?

Comment: It may be either 17.3199999999999 or 17.32000000000001.

Comment: This kind of issues are first programming world problems.

Comment: @svz This doesn't explain why 17.32 behaved different.

Comment: To be precise, it's represented as 17.309999999999998721023075631819665431976318359375.

Comment: To be precise, it's not decimal at all, it's binary. A number like 17.3125 has an exact binary representation because it is 17 + 5/16, but 17.31 has no exact binary representation. You can't express it as a finite sum of powers of two.

Answer (score 6):

Cthulhu and svz's answers are correct. If you want to multiply doubles by 100 and avoid floating point rounding errors, you can use `Math.round()` to round the result to the closest `long` after each multiplication:

```
Double i=17.31;
long j=Math.round(i*100);
System.out.println(j);
```

This will still have floating point error when dealing extremely large (or negative) doubles. The larger the absolute value of a double, the more the difference is between it and the next double that Java can represent. After some point, consecutive doubles are more than an integer apart, and conventional rounding won't be able to smooth out the difference. For the examples you posted, this should work, though.

Answer (score 5):

As has been explained, this is due to very small floating point precision.

This can be resolve via using a Math.round(), command, as follows:

```
long j=Math.round(i*100);
```

This will allow the program to compensate for the very small errors which are inherit using floating point calculations, by not using a floor operation, as the default (long) does.

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the internal representation. If you take a look at i*100 in the first case, you'll see that it is 1730.9999999999998. The cast will only remove the part after the point (truncated).

Comment: point. I fell asleep while typing and posted before waking up.

Answer (score 2):

For value like,
**String value = 1074.6**

Use below code

`double amount = Double.parseDouble(value);`

`String roundedValue = String.valueOf(Math.round(amount * 100))`

You can get result **107460**

Answer (score 0):

When you do this kind of long conversion it's floor. Your 17.31 could actually be 17.30999999999 and that's why it resulted in 1730 instead of 1731.

use i = i * 100, then i.longValue() will solve the problem.

Comment: `i.longValue` acts exactly the same way as `(long) i`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longValue()