# What is wrong with this simple code? Please someone. I tried online IDE and on my eclipse, but I get same output

Tags: java, debugging

I created this simple coin conversion, but for some reason my print output is acting weird, should't it output 12995?

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    double x=129.95;
    int y= (int)(x*100);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Output : 12994

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please respect the rules to post http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask For instance, do not put "Urgent" in your title, this is very aggressive. Then your code is not documented, and the informations given are not enough.

Comment: For a more technical writeup: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It did't took long to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467849/double-multiplied-by-100-and-then-cast-to-long-is-giving-wrong-value

Comment: This may be a bit irrelevant, but why is question getting thumbs down, I understand stackoverflow is filled professional consultants, but doesn't this sort of demotivate to ask us questions.

Comment: It's a cultural thing. It didn't used to be so.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I am of low income, it means a lot to me that I can reach out to your professionals.I am thankful for your generoousity.

Comment: Don't give up on the site. You will get help with genuine problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Math.round will give you your expected answer. You can refer to the comments on your post for more information regarding floating points.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    double x = 129.95;
    int y = (int) Math.round(x * 100);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```